# BLE backup bond information

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I implemented android app which pair and bond with nordic nrf52 ble chip.

I am wondering if its possible in Android to backup or save bond information and reuse it in another android phone in case I lost the bonded phone?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. First, there is no API for it. Second, a bond is tied to a devices's Bluetooth Device Address.

Comment: Can you explain more how its tied to a  a devices's Bluetooth Device Address?

Comment: Bond information consists of a set of keys. To be able to store multiple bonds, each bond info is looked up based on the Bluetooth Device Address of the remote device. For example, device 70:FD:31:03:01:DB may have 183dfa7329ad18c97e39a24adc9a01df as the encryption key.

Comment: Let me explain what i want. I have several nrf52840 ble chipa and one android phone, the phone will bond to all the nrf chips which mean now i have several LTK(Long term key) for each nrf chip. So i want to save these keys as a backup keys in case i lost my phone insted of going to all chips and doing pairing procces again i will use these backup keys.